# What to do with a jpg too warm?

Tags: color, jpeg

I accidentally shot in jpg and I have some way too warm photos.
What can I do with them?

Comment: Please post an example - at the moment, all we can really say is "make them cooler in your favourite image editor".

Comment: Not much... other than maybe convert to B&W.

Comment: Adjustment color balance or white balance in an editor.  But check your display is reasonably calibrated before doing that.

Comment: @Mona Lisa What have you already tried and how did the results not satisfy you?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing magical about JPEG files. It is simply a specification for how to decode specifically formatted image data.

Most image editors can open and work with JPEG files. Use color balance, saturation, curves, or your other favorite controls to change the color to your liking.

Comment: The problem with jpeg files is they preserve only the information needed to display the photo as it is. There is very little latitude to change the color, saturation/curves etc. before things start to get real splotchy.

Comment: Nonsense. Billions of JPEG files have been edited since the format was invented.

Comment: Just because billions have been edited doesn't mean billions have been edited *well*. It is entirely possible to make small changes to the response curve of the R, G, and B channels (which is how color, saturation, contrast, etc. are modified) and make it look well. There are many other editing chores that have nothing to do with response curves that can be applied to jpegs: frequency separation, cloning, etc. But if one shoots to jpeg at 8000K under 2800K lighting you're never going to get it to look like it would if it was shot at 2800K.